# How can I fix iTunes to sync apps and musics?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I have used my own apple ID to sync music and apps for long times. About 5 months ago my friend installed a new app by his own apple ID on my phone and now unfortunately I can't sync any app or music.

iPhone 5s
iTunes version:   12.0.1.26
iOS version:     7.0.4

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Which user/Apple ID is logged into the App Store *on the phone*? Check in Settings and set back to your ID if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @patrix said, check the Apple ID under Settings > iTunes and App Store on your phone. Also, make sure you **DELETED** the app your friend bought with their Apple ID before you try syncing to your iTunes on your computer.

Goes without saying, make sure your **same** Apple ID is used on your iTunes on your computer.